# YouCompleteMe dependency generation failure issue, but it is not a bug

Tags: python, ubuntu, neovim

When I execute:

```
python install.py
```

It will report errors:

```
FAILED

ERROR: the build failed.

NOTE: it is *highly* unlikely that this is a bug but rather that this is a problem with the configuration of your system or a missing dependency. Please carefully read CONTRIBUTING.md and if you're sure that it is a bug, please raise an issue on the issue tracker, including the entire output of this script (with --verbose) and the invocation line used to run it.

The installation failed; please see above for the actual error. In order to get more information, please re-run the command, adding the --verbose flag. If you think this is a bug and you raise an issue, you MUST include the *full verbose* output.

For example, run:/home/ubuntu/miniconda3/bin/python /home/ubuntu/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py --verbose
```

I don't know what the problem is, I guess it may be due to a Python environment issue, but I built the environment using Conda because the system environment will report the same errors as Conda and my own installation of Python 3.11.0 lacks a dependency library. I won't solve this problem, so what caused this error and how to solve it

my conda env:

```
[10:45:47@ubuntu~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe]
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/ubuntu/miniconda3
nvim_py3.11_conda        /home/ubuntu/miniconda3/envs/nvim_py3.11_conda
```

my python in conda:

```
[10:54:16@ubuntu~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe]
$ python --version
Python 3.11.0
```

Comment: Is this all of the output. The error message provided, "please see above for the actual error" implies that there was additional, more meaningful output above this message.

Comment: This is all the information. The reference inside is "CONTABUTING. md", and I still don't know where the error occurred,Even if I add '-- verbose', it's still the same mistake

Comment: Have you installed the system dependencies? `apt install build-essential cmake vim-nox python3-dev`, `apt install mono-complete golang nodejs openjdk-17-jdk openjdk-17-jre npm`.